# Simulating Destructors in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

### Problem Statement

I have two machines, A and B, both running Clojure.

B has some in memory data structure.

A holds an object A_P which is a reference/pointer to some object B_O in B's memory.

Now, as long as A_P is NOT GC-ed by A, I do not want B_O GC-ed by B.

However, once A_P has been GC-ed by A (and nothing else in A referes to B_O, and nothing else in B refers to B_O), then I want B_O to be elegible to be GC-ed.

### Solution in Languages with Destructors

In C++, this is easy -- I use destructors. When A_P gets GC-ed, A sends B a msg to decrement the number of external references to B_O, and when that's 0, and internal refernes to B_0 is also 0, then B_O gets GC-ed.

### Solution in Java/Clojure?

Now, I know that Java does not have destructors. However, I'm wondering if Clojure has a way around this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to search for information about Distributed Garbage Collection. Good luck on that though, because it's inherently problematic because of issues with network reliability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No good solution exists, without a real distributed garbage collector. Even in C++, you cannot do this safely, because you implemented reference counting and pretended it was a real garbage collector; but if two objects point to each other across the machine divide, and are both unreferenced locally, they still both have a nonzero reference count and cannot be collected.

Answer (score 1):

No, Clojure (based on JVM, CLR) doesn't have the "C++ type destructors" because of the automatic memory management model of JVM. There are things like finalizers but it is recommended to not use them. Instead you should model your solution based on message passing mechanism rather then A machine holding "pointer/reference" to data in B. I know this answer is very high level because you haven't provide any specific problem details in your question. If you need more details about how to solve a particular problem please provide the complete context and I am sure someone will able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inherently difficult problem: distributed garbage problem is really hard if not impossible to get right.

However you might just be able to make it work using Java finalisers and overriding the `finalize()` method. You can then implement a messaging technique similar to the one you describe for C++.

This will have issues in the more general case (it won't help you with circular references across machines as amalloy points out) and there are some other quirks to be aware of (mostly around your lack of control over exactly when the finaliser gets called) but you might be able to get it to work in your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a data structure like a ref or atom for holding data structure A somewhere inside it, you can use listeners for monitoring the state of that structure for removals of A, and those listeners can send appropriate message to B.  `clojure.data/diff` could be really useful for finding the structures that were removed.

The other option would be to have, immediately after the A structure is dereferenced, the function responsible for doing so send the message.  As part of this though, make sure that that code was actually responsible for the removal of A, and not some other update.